# Executing command with system() returns 256 times the return value ( << 8). What is the point of this?

Tags: c++, return-value, bit-shift

It took me a while to find the solution to the issue I was having in relation to this:

```
status = system("[ -e myFile ] && exit 1 || exit 101");

if(status == 101)
{
    ...
```

The return value was being sent back as 25856 (101*256 (or 101 << 8)).

None of the answers I found indicated the REASON that this effective 256 multiplication occurs...

Anyone able to provide an explanation for me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as the language standards are concerned, the return value of `system()` is implementation-defined.  There is no justification there for assuming that the return value of `system()` has any relationship to the exit status of the command that is run.

With a POSIX-conformant library, however, the return value of a successful call to `system()` is defined to be in the format used by the `wait`(2) function.  I speculate that this is for consistency, and perhaps also for ease of implementation.  In any event, that return value carries information not only about the exit status, but also about how the process terminated  -- normally, or because of a signal -- and other information.  On such a system, one is expected to check whether the process exited normally by applying the `WIFEXITED()` macro to the code, and to extract the exit status itself via the `WEXITSTATUS()` macro.  These macros will be declared in `sys/wait.h`.

That's all very C-ish, of course.  There is likely a more C++-ish alternative to some of that.

Answer (score 0):

For the return value of any system call, the high 8 bits are the exit status and the low 8 are the signal ID. To retrieve the exit status, like you found out, you must shift the value 8 bits right.

Comment: I'm looking for any documentation to back that up but I can't seem to find anything

Comment: without proper documentation quote this will probably be downvoted

Answer (score 0):

The return value of [`system`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/system) is implementation defined. Especially, it's not defined to return the value that the executed command passed to `exit`.

*Why* does your system in particular happen to not return only the return value of the command, but also a low order byte that happened to be 0... well that also depends on which implementation you are using.

In case you happen to be using POSIX, you can read this [manual](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/system.html) to find out what `system` returns:

> If command is not a null pointer, system() shall return the termination status of the command language interpreter in the format specified by waitpid()

And the [manual](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/waitpid.html) for `waitpid` tells you what information can be interpreted from the return value, and how.